# How can i filter by field when have the same fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to do filter on the field `type` on a doc,and the doc has two object `message` and `tags`, but both `message` and `tags` have the `type` field.

***Doc:***

```
 {
 "message":{
  "type":2,
  "body":"test"
 },
 "tags":{
    "tagname":"td",
     "type":0
    }
 }
```

How can i filter the doc with message's type is 2 ?,i tried this but no result returned.

```
"filter" : {
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "bool" : {
          "should" : {
            "match" : {
              "type" : {
                "query" : 2,
                "type" : "boolean",
                "operator" : "AND"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply filtering on the field `message.type` will work given that the field `message` is not of `nested` type:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "message.type": {
        "value": 2
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If `message` is of `nested` type then use the following nested query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "message",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "message.type": {
            "value": 2
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah！it woks! Thanks.